# How to Override Default Working Directory for Pycharm Run Configurations

Tags: pycharm, pytest

In Pycharm `2021.3.2`, every time I click on a test in order to run it, the working directory of the newly created Run Configuration sets itself to the directory which the test file is in.

The docs seem to reflect this: [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#run-debug-parameters)

> When a default run/debug configuration is created by the keyboard shortcut ⌃ ⇧ R, or by choosing Run from the context menu of a script, the working directory is the one that contains the executable script. This directory may differ from the project directory.

However, I would like to set a default working directory which every dynamically generated Run Configuration in my project uses. I tried creating a pytest template and setting the working directory there to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to set "pytest" as the default test runner. PyCharm seems to use the autodetect runner by default (and thus the autodetect template, not the pytest template). The following steps helped in my case: https://jaketrent.com/post/pytest-use-working-directory-pycharm/